# Accessing variables from other function

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, scope

so I did a project from freeCodeCamp in which i have to get your location and show the weather in that location. Everything works (made it work through trial and error) however i do not quite understand why i can access `url` variable in `putInHtml` function, because all the variables are declared in the `getPosition` function.

Here is all the code:

```js
function getPosition(){
  var lat, lon, url;
  if(navigator.geolocation){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else {
    alert('Cant find location');
  }
}
function showPosition(pos) { /// paima objecta is getCurrentPosition    
  lat = pos.coords.latitude;
  lon = pos.coords.longitude;   
  url = "https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?lat="+lat+"&lon="+lon;
}  
getPosition();

function putInHtml(){
  
  $.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url: url,
    dataType:"json",
    success: function(data){

      $('#location').html(data.name);
      $('#temp').html(data.main.temp);
      $('#desc').html(data.weather[0].description)
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
          console.log(error);
    }
  })   
} 

$("#spust").click(putInHtml);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="text-center">Weather App</h1>

<h2 id="location"></h2>
<h1 id="temp"></h1>
<p id="desc"></p>
<button id="spust">Spust</button>
```

Well, somehow it doesn't work here, but it does in codepen.

Comment: Are you sure you have the exact same code on Codepen? Because it shouldn't work. The `url` variable is defined in the scope of `showPosition`, so using it in another function/scope should be impossible.

Comment: I'm quite sure, here's the link to codepen: https://codepen.io/benasl/pen/WZRYzg?editors=0011

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `lat`, `lon`, and `url` variables are not in scope with the rest of your functions.  You could resolve this by declaring the variables outside of your function like so:

```
var lat, lon, url;
function getPosition(){
  //Removed your variables from here
  if(navigator.geolocation){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else {
    alert('Cant find location');
  }
}
function showPosition(pos) { /// paima objecta is getCurrentPosition    
  lat = pos.coords.latitude;
  lon = pos.coords.longitude;   
  url = "https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?lat="+lat+"&lon="+lon;
}  
getPosition();

function putInHtml(){

  $.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url: url,
    dataType:"json",
    success: function(data){

      $('#location').html(data.name);
      $('#temp').html(data.main.temp);
      $('#desc').html(data.weather[0].description)
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
          console.log(error);
    }
  })   
} 

$("#spust").click(putInHtml);
```

Now your variables will be in scope of all of your functions, since we have added them to the global scope.  Read more on scope [here.](https://toddmotto.com/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-javascript-scope/)  Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you, putting those variables outside all the functions was in my initial code, however when i tried putting them inside the getPosition function the whole thing still works, thus my question:  why does it work?

Comment: @BenasLengvinas If you declared those variables within the getPosition function without using the var keyword, JavaScript will automatically assign them to the global scope.  And since they'll be assigned in the global scope, all functions will be able to access them.  One of the many JS pitfalls :)

Comment: That's the thing - i did declare using the var keyword. Here's the codepen: https://codepen.io/benasl/pen/WZRYzg?editors=0011

Comment: Although you did declare using the var keyword within the getPosition() function, that alone will not add them to the global scope.  So when it gets to your showPosition() function, that function cannot see those variables because they are out of scope.  As a result, since you did not use the var keyword, it will automagically assign those variables to the global scope in showPosition().  A major JS pitfall.  I highly recommend you read some articles/watch some YT videos on scope.  It'll blow your mind!  And it's a very good thing to know about the language, and any language in general.  :)

Comment: Ohhh the showPosition function...okay, thank you so much!

Comment: Sure thing!  Happy coding, and feel free to reach out to me if you have any questions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155361/discussion-between-benas-lengvinas-and-alexander-edwards).

Answer (score 2):

In this function,

```
function showPosition(pos) { /// paima objecta is getCurrentPosition    
 lat = pos.coords.latitude;
 lon = pos.coords.longitude;   
 url = "https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?lat="+lat+"&lon="+lon;
}
```

**url** is in global scope since you are not using **var**

```
var url = "https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?lat="+lat+"&lon="+lon;
```

declaring it with **var** would limit its scope to showPosition function and then you won't be able to use outside that function.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript scope is function based. The `showPosition` function is a separate function from the `getPosition` function, and they are peers; that is, `showPosition` is not nested inside `getPosition`, so it has no visibility of the variables scoped to `showPosition`. If you want to give `showPosition` visibility to `url`, then `url` must be declared higher up in a scope that contains both functions. For example the global scope, a function (such as an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)), or an ES6 [class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) that contains both functions. Or you can change the declaration of `url` to an ES6 [`let` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) to introduce block scope that wraps both functions.

Answer (score 0):

Define the global variables outside of any function so you can access or update it inside or outside of any function:

```
 var url; //This makes the URL globally defined

function getPosition(){
      var lat, lon, url;
      if(navigator.geolocation){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
      } else {
        alert('Cant find location');
      }
    }
    function showPosition(pos) { /// paima objecta is getCurrentPosition    
      lat = pos.coords.latitude;
      lon = pos.coords.longitude;   
      url = "https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?lat="+lat+"&lon="+lon;
    }  
    getPosition();

    function putInHtml(){

      $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url: url,
        dataType:"json",
        success: function(data){

          $('#location').html(data.name);
          $('#temp').html(data.main.temp);
          $('#desc').html(data.weather[0].description)
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
              console.log(error);
        }
      })   
    } 

    $("#spust").click(putInHtml);
```

Comment: My initial code was with those variables in the global scope, however then i tried to add those vars to getPosition function the whole thing was still working, therefore my question: why does it work?